# ¿Por qué obtengo error en bucle for cuando digo que ( i ) va a ser igual a la posición de mi array?

Tags: java, array

Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]
num cannot be resolved to a variable
num cannot be resolved to a variable

¿Qué solución alternativa hay para inicializar un array con varias posiciones en caso de que esta no sea válida?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PerezSuarezCristoRuben_Ejercicios_en_casa_1_04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("¿Por cuántos dígitos va a estar compuesto su número?:");
        int numberLength = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberLength; i++) {

            System.out.println("Introduzca los dígitos de su número de 1 en 1:");
            int userNumber = sc.nextInt();

            int num[i] = userNumber;

        }

        System.out.println("Introduzca el dígito que quiere añadir:");
        int userDigit = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca la posición del dígito que quiere sustituir:");
        int userPosition = sc.nextInt();

        num[userPosition] = userDigit;

        System.out.println("Este su número con el arreglo incluido: " + num[0]);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: La logica es tan confusa que no logro identificar que trataste de hacer, mas alla que esto : int num[i] = userNumber; no va a funcionar nunca, porque num no es un array...

Comment: como dice @gbianchi no funciona por num no es un array...  falta declarar el arreglo antes del for...  `int num[] = new int[numberLength];` y remover el int del `int num[i] = userNumber;` ya que solo necesitas almacenar el valor en el indice pero no declarar una variable

Comment: Básicamente si el bucle for está en la vuelta 0 ( i = 0 ), array int num[] señalara hacia la posición 0 ( int num [ i ] ) porque i vale 0 y el valor de esa posición será igual al número del usuario, así sucesivamente, rellenando las posiciones del array segun la vuelta en la que se encuentre el bucle, no se si es posible hacerlo así no domino la sintaxis completa.

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme chicos aun estoy desarrollando la lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Te flato declarar el arreglo num

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    
    public class PerezSuarezCristoRuben_Ejercicios_en_casa_1_04{
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            System.out.println("¿Por cuántos dígitos va a estar compuesto su número?:");
            int numberLength = sc.nextInt();
    
            int []num =new int[numberLength];//declaras el arreglo con el tamaño que le da numberLenght
    
            for (int i = 0; i < numberLength; i++) {
    
                System.out.println("Introduzca los dígitos de su número de 1 en 1:");
                int userNumber = sc.nextInt();
    
                num[i] = userNumber;
    
            }
    
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));//imprime los valores que tiene el arreglo
    
            System.out.println("Introduzca el dígito que quiere añadir:");
            int userDigit = sc.nextInt();
    
            System.out.println("Introduzca la posición del dígito que quiere sustituir:");
            int userPosition = sc.nextInt();
            //las posiciones de  los arreglos empiezan en 0 por ejemplo si tua arreglo tiene 3 valores como indice tendra a 0,1,2    
            num[userPosition] = userDigit;
    
            System.out.println("Este su número con el arreglo incluido: " + Arrays.toString(num));
            
        }
    
    }
```